# javascript - How to make this array work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I am trying to complete an assignment in Woz-U Exeter LMS (an online coding course). I cannot figure out how to create the correct code for the following set of instructions:

1. Within the javascript file, create a function named idCard
2. Create two variables named age and phoneNumber that pulls in the value of the corresponding input using DOM
3. Create an empty array named numberArray
4. Push both the age and phoneNumber variables into your empty array
5. Create a for loop that will loop through numberArray
6. Write an if/elseif statement within the for loop. Check to see if the numberArray at index i is less than or equal to 100. If it is, use DOM innerHTML to write "Age: " plus the variable age. Check to see if the numberArray at index i is greater than 100. If it is, use DOM innerHTML to write "Phone Number: " plus the variable phoneNumber

HTML FILE EXCERPT:

```
   <input id="age">
   <input id="phoneNumber">

<br><button onclick="idCard()">Get ID card!</button>

<div id="idCard">

   <p id="postAge"></p>
   <p id="postPhoneNumber"></p>

</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT FILE EXCERPT:

```
function idCard(idCard) {
  var age = parseInt(document.getElementById("age").value);
  var phoneNumber = parseInt(document.getElementById("phoneNumber").value);

  var numberArray = [];
  numberArray.push("age").value;
  numberArray.push("phoneNumber").value;

  for (var i = 0; i < numberArray.length; i++);{
    if (numberArray[i] <= 100){
      document.getElementById("postAge").innerHTML = ("Age:" + " " + age);
    }
    else if (numberArray[i] > 100){
      document.getElementById("postPhoneNumber").innerHTML = ("Phone Number" + " " + phoneNumber);
    }
  }   
}
```

When I try to click the onCLick button, I expect the inputted data to post to the corresponding  paragraph tags. What happens instead is that the data clears from my input form and just disappears.

Comment: First thing I can see is `numberArray.push("age").value;` should be `numberArray.push(age);`, and likewise for the phonenumber. You've already got the value and you want to use the variable `age` not a string.

Comment: And a couple of typos: `for (var i = 0; i + numberArray.length; i++);{` should be `for (var i = 0; i < numberArray.length; i++) {`

Comment: @Andy Thank you. After implementing your changes, clicking the onClick button didn't freeze the page, as had previously occured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### TL;DR

Is this what you want to achieve:

```
// Cache DOM
const button = document.querySelector('#clickButton')

button.addEventListener('click', idCard)

function idCard() {
  const ageElement = document.querySelector('#postAge')
  const phoneNumberElement = document.querySelector('#postPhoneNumber')
  const age = document.querySelector('#age').value
  const phoneNumber = document.querySelector('#phoneNumber').value
  const numberArray = [age, phoneNumber]

  /* Seems a bit redundant for static additions */
  // numberArray.push(age)
  // numberArray.push(numberArray)

  numberArray.forEach(x => (
    x <= 100 
      ? ageElement.textContent = `Age: ${age}` 
      : phoneNumberElement.textContent = `Phone: ${phoneNumber}`
  ))
}
```

### Mistake in your code

When looking at your code first thing I see is a semicolon between you `for` loop and the `opening` bracket. I haven't really debugged your code to be certain but I guess that is where you is lies.

### Note on example

Currently for `ageElement` and `phoneNumber` I use a querySelector. However every time when a user hits the button JavaScript will look at the DOM and fetches the required DOM elements. Now in this case this might be a bit overkill since those two DOM elements are not changing, from a perfomance point of view it might be better to "cache" those elements as I did with the button. Only once when the JavaScript is loaded. (Fetching the DOM on each function call might be useful when you are have dynamically added DOM elements)

I hope this answers your question, if so please mark it as answered :) If not feel free to ask questions.

Answer (score -1):

I debugged your code and marked corrections with `x` after the line. You weren't far away. @Rick van den Broek makes some good suggestions for further improvement in his answer.

```js
function idCard() {
  var age = parseInt(document.getElementById("age").value);
  var phoneNumber = parseInt(document.getElementById("phoneNumber").value);

  var numberArray = [];
  numberArray.push(age); // x
  numberArray.push(phoneNumber); // x

  for (var i = 0; i < numberArray.length; i++) { // x x
    if (numberArray[i] <= 100) {
      document.getElementById("postAge").innerHTML = ("Age:" + " " + numberArray[i]); // x
    } else if (numberArray[i] > 100) {
      document.getElementById("postPhoneNumber").innerHTML = ("Phone Number" + " " + numberArray[i]); // x
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="age">
<input id="phoneNumber">

<br><button onclick="idCard()">Get ID card!</button>

<div id="idCard">

  <p id="postAge"></p>
  <p id="postPhoneNumber"></p>

</div>
```